# conan ...[clos ed]

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I need to compile three packages from the same code, but the includes(same name xyz.h) in the cmake should get picked from different location for each of the package.
As I am new to c++ and conan, please give pointers.

Comment: Do you want to provide 3 binary packages using 1 single code, is that correct? Each package will contain only different headers, what about libraries? Is it a single project, or are there sub projects?

Comment: same project, same libraries used.

Comment: it's not clear enough, why do you need different headers for the same library? Please, provide a detailed description, your case is not clear. Details are important to understand what's the best approach to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should be implementing the logic you want in your `package()` method:

```
def package(self):
    # for example, headers are different based on OS
    if self.settings.os == "Windows":
       self.copy("*.h", src="win", dst="include")
    elif self.settings.os == "Linux":
       self.copy("*.h, src="nix", dst="include")
    ...
```

This assumes you have different `win` and `nix` **folders** in your layout when you build the package.

Then you do the `conan create` as many times as necessary:

```
$ conan create . user/channel -s os=Windows  # default if you are in a Win machine
# or
$ conan create . user/channel -s os=Linux # default if you are in a Linux machin
```

Every package will end with different headers in the final *include* folder